# Running flutter project from visuel studio code

Tags: flutter

how to launch the execution of a flutter project in chrome instead of the emulator from visual studio code because I have the emulator which does not work.

thank you for helping me.

what i expected to happen :

running app on chrome from visuel studio code

Answer (score 1):

you have to make sure that web is enabled for your project
here's a link to add web support for your current project
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/web

once you make sure web is enabled you can just run

```
flutter run -d chrome
```